# cant get ES modules to work with import or require

Tags: javascript, import, require, node-fetch, inquirer

I'm building a command line based application and was using require to link various files and node modules. I have previously used Require with no issues and now I get nothing but errors.

Error with Require:

**Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ./lib/departments.cjs not supported,
Instead change the require of inquirer.js in ./lib/departments.cjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.**

After this I tried multiple methods to get it to work again, but had no luck so I tried to switch to import. When I switched to import I got this message:

**SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

Ive tried to add **type: "module"** to my package.json file, but I don't know if I am putting it in the wrong place or what.
My JSON file looks like this

```
{

  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "directories": {
     "lib": "lib"
},
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node server.js"
},
  "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "git+https://.git"
},
 "author": "",
 "license": "MIT",
 "bugs": {
     "url": "https://issues"
},
 "homepage": "https://#readme",
 "dependencies": {
     "console.table": "^0.10.0",
     "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
     "express": "^4.18.1",
     "inquirer": "^9.1.1",
     "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
     "node-fetch": "^2.6.7"
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using `.cjs` extension for your js file, `cjs` is a commonJS file which doesn't support `import`. You need to use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

It's worth mentioning that ES modules cannot be imported using the require() function of `cjs`.

Comment: Even with the normal .js file naming Im still running into issues with both methods

Comment: In the import statement are you calling passing the file extension as well? In some cases you need to pass `import something from './file.js'` instead of `'./file`.

Comment: ill try switching it around!